# How to create Singleton with async method?

Tags: c#

I want to have an singleton, say `Printer`, with one method, say `bool addToPrintQueue(Document document)`. `addToPrintQueue` should be async (should return immediately), return `true` if added to queue and `false` if document already in `queue`. How to write such method and what should I use for `queue` processing? (should it be separate thread?)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you need a singleton here, an asynchronous thread with locking should do just fine here

```
 // create a document queue
    private static Queue<string> docQueue = new Queue<string>();

    // create async caller and result handler
    IAsyncResult docAdded = null;
    public delegate bool AsyncMethodCaller(string doc);

    // 
    public void Start()
    {
        // create a dummy doc
        string doc = "test";

        // start the async method
        AsyncMethodCaller runfirstCaller = new AsyncMethodCaller(DoWork);
        docAdded = runfirstCaller.BeginInvoke(doc,null,null);
        docAdded.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        // get the result
        bool b = runfirstCaller.EndInvoke(docAdded);
    }


    // add the document to the queue
    bool DoWork(string doc)
    {

        lock (docQueue)
        {
            if (docQueue.Contains(doc))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                docQueue.Enqueue(doc);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t `docQueue` be private?

Comment: It should be - I copied the bulk of this from some code I had previously written, in that case the queue needed to be public, I just didn't pick up on it in this instance

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider doing [Event-based Async pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx). Since each asynchronous event has corresponding completed  event that is raised when the method finishes. This  will tell if document is added to queue or it failed.

I would create `Printer.addToPrintQueue` event and let subscribers subscribe to it.

```
printer.addToPrintQueueCompleted += _addToPrinterQueueCompleted;
printer.addToPrintQueueAsync();


private void _addToPrinterQueueCompleted(object sender, addToPrintQueueCompletedEventArgs e)
{ /* ... */ }
```