# how to create singleton which always running in separate thread?

Tags: c#

I would like to rephrase my previous question [How to create Singleton with async method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783776/how-to-create-singleton-with-async-method)

Imagine messaging application (like icq) - something that should be always connected to server and can post messages.

I need to implment class `Connection`. It should be singleton, because it contains "socket" inside and that socket should persist during entirely application lifetime.

Then I want to implement async method `Connection.postMessage`

Because `postMessage` can take significant ammount of time:

- `postMessage` should be async
- `postMessage` should queue messages if neccesary

Note my application posts dozens messages per second, so it is not appropiate to create new Thread for each `postMessage` call.

I diffenetely need to create exactly one extra thread for messages posting but I don't know where and how.

**upd:** good example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You question, just like the previous one, has nothing to do with singletons. You want to know how to create a message queue. It just happens that you're making that a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Postmessage (itself) should not be async .

It should

- be Thread-safe
- ensure the Processing thread is running
- queue the message (ConcurrentQueue)
- return

And the Processing Thread should

- Wait on the Queue
- Process the messages
- maybe Terminate itself when idle for xx milliseconds

What you have is a classic Producer/Consumer situation with 1 Consumer and multiple Producers.

PostMessage is the entry-point for all producers.

Comment: agree, sound like this should work for my application, will try to google for c# implementation of this pattern. but I think i have a question, how to "ensure the Processing thread is running". How to create and manager processing thread?

Comment: @javapowered: `var t = new Thread(...);` and `if(t.IsAlive)`.

Answer (score 1):

jp,

You're looking at a classic producer/consumer problem here... During initialisation the `Connection` should create a `MessageQueue` start a `Sender` in it's own background thread.

Then the connection `posts` just messages to the queue, for the Sender to pickup and forward when ready.

The tricky bit is managing the maximum queue size... If the producer consistently outruns the consumer then queue can grow to an unmanagable size. The simplest approach is to block the producer thread until the queue is no longer full. This can be done with a back-off-ARQ. ie: `while(queue.isFull) sleep(100, "milliseconds"); queue.add(message);` If you don't require 100% transmission (like a chat-app, for instance) then you can simply throw a MessageQueueFullException, and the poor client will just have to get over it... just allways allow them to resubmit later... allowing the user manage the retrys for you.

That's how I'd tackle it anyway. I'll be interested to see what others suggestions are muted.

Hope things work out for you. Cheers. Keith.

Comment: That's not **blocking** the producer thread. That's busy waiting.

Comment: Yeah... it's busy waiting, which at 1/10th of second is fast enough, and not *too* busy... as for NOT blocking the producer thread... Huh? The producer's not going ANYWHERE until the queue becomes not-full... I'd call that constipated enough.

Comment: I said "The simplest approach is to block the producer thread"... which a not-too-busy wait will do adequately. You're from the "never use goto" camp, aren't you... Sigh. I just write software that works.

Comment: corletkk: I can live with a goto or 2, but Sleep() in a Thread is almost always wrong. We don't know enough about the system to say if it's adequate or acceptable.

Comment: I never said busy waiting is the devil. I said that it is not "blocking until it is no longer full". It's "polling at a regular interval". I think I'm more from the "call things by their name" camp.